# Import UTF 8 - without BOM (CSV file) into Microsoft SQL Server using the SSIS Package is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, utf-8, ssis

I am trying to import an UTF-8 `.CSV` file into SQL Server using SSIS.

In SSIS, I have chosen the following in the **Flat file connection manager.**:

- Code Page = 65001 (UTF -8)
- Unicode = Un-checked
- Advanced: Data type = DT_WSTR.
- OLE DB destination: Created a table with a `NVARCHAR` type

When I run the package, the data load is terribly slow. Could you please advise me on this? 
But if I import a fat file (in ANSI format), the data load is very fast.

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you try using `Bulk import` ?

Comment: No. I dont have the access to use Bulk Import.

Comment: Are there Check-constraints in the Tablet? Do you use the fast-Load-option for the OLED-Provider?

Comment: Yes. I am using the Fast - Load option.